# Odata - New Hire Detection

Tags: c#, odata, sap-successfactors

I need to find New Hires that have been entered into Success Factors and will be starting in the future via OData.

The following C# based query is what I'm using:

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);

var newHires = EmpEmployment
.Expand("userNav")
.Where (e => e.startDate >= tomorrow);
```

The above query returns staff who have a startDate in the future however the User expansion does not find any matching entries and is null.

The issue appears to be that the User table is only populated with entries for the person when the start date is reached. This is a problem because I want to create them in other systems in advance.

Does anyone know if this is normal or thoughts around how I can obtain details like firstname, lastname of future employees who have been entered in the system?

Comment: Do you have tried post this query using HTTP GET?

Comment: Testing with HTTP directly and via LinqPad give the same result, the platform just doesn’t seem to present the user data until the start date is reached.

Comment: So you only need Employee Central information for new-hires, not only from RCM (Recruiting Management)?
For second there is JobOffer entity with possible custom field custStartDate and Candidate entity (not User).

Comment: I can’t access the JobOffer and related tables so I’m guessing either the permissions are wrong or more likely we don’t have RCM access.

Comment: It seems you have only Employee Central functionality switched on. The only way to get New hires is asking functional consultant, because it depends on many settings and project-specific.

Comment: Thanks lliya, please make that an answer and I’ll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use EmpEmployment entity from Employee Central. The required date could be retrieved from RCM (Recruitment Management).

There is no clear answer to your question because customizing depends on the project; you should ask functional consultant responsible for EC what the way to get New hires startDate.